# Connect to Sybase using PHP und Windows (XAMPP)

Tags: php, xampp, sybase

Im trying to connect to a sybase db with PHP, I'm running under Windows using XAMPP (Prototyping).

```
$conn = sybase_connect($servername, $username, $password);
```

I found out, that there should be an [Interface "file" (under Servername)](http://php.net/manual/de/function.sybase-connect.php) but I have no idea where to find it under Windows especially when using XAMPP nor how to fill it. The informations I find on the Internetz where mostly for Unix or they're either wrong or somehow incompletely.

Hope someone has an idea.

Comment: The interfaces file needs to be in the SAP/Sybase SDK installation.  You will need the SDK to have the proper binaries to connect.

Comment: That sounds complicated. Is there an usable step by step documentation out there?

Comment: Well, since Sybase was a company, and not a database - putting details about the actual product and version would help us to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Sybase version? PHP version ?

Comment: hello, did you find the solution ? Please explain what is your conclusion .I am worried more because of the poor documentation available on the web.